# Display diff-style context marker as first line of Vim buffer?

Tags: vim, macvim

Diff context markers (or whatever they're actually called) are helpful when viewing diffs of large files. In fact, I realized it might be helpful to have such a line at the at the top of the Vim buffer at all times:

```
@@ -30,4 +30,16 @@ describe('memoize', function() {
```

To be clear, I'm not talking about viewing diffs in Vim; I'm talking about viewing JavaScript files and other source files, but having the first line of the buffer provide context for the rest of the buffer.

Does anyone know of a plugin which does this?

Comment: Are you looking to put the [function name on the status bar](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13634826/438329)?

Comment: Something along those lines, yes. Thanks for the link.